# Accuracy of LSTM model is very low

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to build a model to predict text.

The x_train is of shape: (19992, 40, 1)

```
array([[[0.00680272],
        [0.01417234],
        [0.        ],
        ...,

        [0.01473923],
        [0.        ],
        [0.0085034 ]]])
```

The y_train is of shape: (19992, 42) (It is one-hot encoded)

```
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

My model is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(40,1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(42, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now on training my model even with 150 epochs, I am only able to achieve an accuracy of 0.512.
What should I improve in the model to increase its accuracy?

```
Train on 15993 samples, validate on 3999 samples
Epoch 1/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 23s 3ms/step - loss: 2.9527 - acc: 0.2013 - val_loss: 2.8762 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 2/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 23s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8670 - acc: 0.2111 - val_loss: 2.8678 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 3/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 23s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8548 - acc: 0.2117 - val_loss: 2.8615 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 4/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 22s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8516 - acc: 0.2121 - val_loss: 2.8629 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 5/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 22s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8447 - acc: 0.2117 - val_loss: 2.8663 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 6/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 21s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8445 - acc: 0.2133 - val_loss: 2.8657 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 7/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 22s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8404 - acc: 0.2134 - val_loss: 2.8657 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 8/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 21s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8401 - acc: 0.2117 - val_loss: 2.8673 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 9/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 21s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8391 - acc: 0.2139 - val_loss: 2.8657 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 10/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 22s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8412 - acc: 0.2141 - val_loss: 2.8642 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 11/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 21s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8394 - acc: 0.2149 - val_loss: 2.8680 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 12/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 22s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8404 - acc: 0.2154 - val_loss: 2.8658 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 13/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 22s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8380 - acc: 0.2161 - val_loss: 2.8672 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 14/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 22s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8384 - acc: 0.2169 - val_loss: 2.8674 - val_acc: 0.2061
Epoch 15/15
15993/15993 [==============================] - 22s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8378 - acc: 0.2171 - val_loss: 2.8702 - val_acc: 0.2061
```

Comment: could you provide the training traceback ?

Comment: @BenjaminBreton I am sorry, but I'm not quite sure what 'training traceback' means.... Do you mean the output that we get during each epoch???

Comment: Yes copy and paste what is printed in the terminal when you train the model

Comment: @BenjaminBreton I've added training traceback for 15 epochs. :)

Comment: what are you trying to predict ? From what I see here, you are taking the info of the whole sequence, and are trying to predict one class out of 42 different classes.

Comment: Try using adam optimizer

Comment: @BenjaminBreton Yeah, That's exactly what I am trying to predict. The prediction should be a 1x42 array with all elements having value ~0 except one(having value ~1)

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa I tried... but no luck :(

Comment: Try learning rate decay

Comment: @WinterSoldier does it correspond to an element of the sequence, or are the 42 classes unrelated to the 40 steps in the sequence ?

Comment: @BenjaminBreton The elements are actually characters to be predicted, to be precise my data contains 42 different characters, which I have one-hot encoded in y_train. The x_train consists of sentences, each of 40 characters long. The model task is to output a character when given a sentence of length 40. So example my sentence is  "Hello_World"....then my x_train will have "Hello_Worl" and my y_train will have 'd'

Comment: @WinterSoldier Ok, I got it, try lowering the learning rate and put higher values of **keep_proba** for Dropouts (like 0.8). It seems like the task is too hard, and the network is not learning anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are considering LSTM-based character-level language model. This kind of models typically use multidimensional embeddings as inputs, not just 1-dimensional scalars. So for Keras you may try the following net architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(42, output_dim=64, input_length=40))
model.add(LSTM(256,input_shape=(40,1),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(42,activation='softmax'))
```

where `output_dim` is number of embedding dimensions. The inputs to this net are integer matrices `[batch_size x input_length]`, where each element is char index. Take a look at [this post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-character-based-neural-language-model-keras/) for details. Hope this helps!